# Error mysqli::ssl_set(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to update some code to use a secure connection required by the new environment. I feel I have implemented the change correctly but I am getting the error: mysqli::ssl_set(): Couldn't fetch mysqli which seems to say mysqli is not initializing which does not make sense since if I remove the bit about SSL that I added it connects but is rejected due to lack of SSL. Any ideas as to where this is going wrong?

```
public static function singleton($db_host, $db_login, $db_password, $db_name) {
    if (!self::$instance) {
        self::$instance = new mysqli($db_host,$db_login, $db_password, $db_name);
        self::$instance->ssl_set( NULL,NULL, "/var/www/html/classes/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem", NULL, NULL );
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            ErrLog::write("Error while connecting to DB.");
            return null;
        }
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  I had to init the object then add the ssl and some parameters to the connect call.

```
        self::$instance = new mysqli();
        self::$instance->init(); 
        self::$instance->ssl_set( NULL,NULL, "/var/www/html/lib/classes/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem", NULL, NULL );
        self::$instance->real_connect($db_host,$db_login, $db_password, $db_name, 3306, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
```